# Full outer join SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sales from a department as

```
MonthYear  Total
-----------------
April2016    2
Sept2016     2
Oct2016      6
Jan2016      8
Feb2016      9
```

Using the `Sales` and `Date` table, linked on `SalesDate` and `Date`, I want to do a full outer join and return the missing months as below:

```
MonthYear  Total
-----------------
Jan2016      8
Feb2016      9
Mar2016      0
April2016    2
May2016      0
June2016     0
July2016     0
Aug2016      0
Sept2016     2
Oct2016      6
Nov2016      0
Dec2016      0
```

Can you please advise how to do this? When I do the full outer join, I don't get the missing months

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Don't hesitate on looking thru the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) or in 
the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be sure about how to ask questions. 
Asking something like "I want to do xyz" with no attempts of code included or info about the errors you got, sample data and desired results is likely to be closed due to lack of info to answer. 
Remember to add all the relevant code, error logs and everything in your question as plain text, so we can provide better help. :)

Comment: make driver table [DATE] table and join your other FACT or DIMs to it.

Comment: A full outer join would work if you did it correctly.  However, if you don't post your code, we can't tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: What's the table structure and data types? Is there a `MONTH` data type I'm not aware of in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `left join`.  Something like this:

```sql
SELECT dt.MonthYear, coalesce(s.total, 0)
FROM datetable dt LEFT JOIN
     sales s ON dt.MonthYear = s.MonthYear
```

Comment: thank you so much the coalesce(s.total, 0) worked a charm x